# MongoDB DB initialization keeps giving constant errors

Tags: ruby, mongodb, networking, port

I have executed `mongod` in a command window on default `localhost:27017`.
Now, in another cmd window, if I try to create an instance of `Mongo::Client` in IRB, I keep getting a repeated error message:

```
db = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://localhost:27017')
# D, [2018-02-08T20:19:08.300889 #2392] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
# D, [2018-02-08T20:19:08.300889 #2392] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server localhost:27017 initializing.
# D, [2018-02-08T20:19:08.317054 #2392] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - connect(2) for [::1]:27017
#=> #<Mongo::Client:0x39242556 cluster=localhost:27017>

# D, [2018-02-08T20:19:18.321547 #2392] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - connect(2) for [::1]:27017
# D, [2018-02-08T20:19:28.324674 #2392] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. - connect(2) for [::1]:27017
# ...
```

Basically the error that I keep getting indefinitely is `An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.` Although commands like `db.database.name` returns the correct name. How do I fix it ? Does this have something to do with using an IPv4 socket to connect to an IPv6 network ?

Comment: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#localhost-binding-compatibility-changes

Comment: Alright, but then isn't localhost 127.0.0.1 ? So then how does it matter ? Thats what I was confused about because 127.0.0.1 is the IPv4 loopback address and not IPv6

Comment: `localhost` can be both, `127.0.0.1` and `::1`